# Multiple Table Trigger Update/Delete/Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, triggers

I'm having troubles creating a SQL Server trigger to do what I want. I don't have much experience with triggers.

Basically I have a table, let's call it `cluster_metadata`, with metadata that describes certain attributes about an object. Then I have a second table, let's call it `activities_table`, with user entered data that may pertain to certain objects in the `cluster_metadata` table.

The `cluster_metadata` table is user updatable however new rows are created and deleted using a stored procedure, users can only update specific values.

The `activities_table` is completely user driven and users can insert/modify and delete rows.

I need a trigger that joins the data and will update the table on any modification of the `cluster_metadata` or `activities_table`.

For simplicity I've trimmed down the number of columns but the tables look something like this.

`cluster_metadata`:

```
+----------------------------------+
|  Cluster  |  Eligible  |  Group  |
+----------------------------------+
|  Cluster1 |    True    |    1    |
|  Cluster2 |    True    |    1    |
|  Cluster3 |    True    |    2    |
|  Cluster4 |    False   |    2    |
|  Cluster5 |    True    |    3    |
|  Cluster6 |    True    |    4    |
+----------------------------------+
```

`activities_table`:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|  Activity  |  ID  |  Group  |  Start Date  |
+--------------------------------------------+
|  Patches   | 1000 |    1    |  02-01-2015  |
|  Patches   | 1000 |    2    |  02-10-2015  |
|  Patches   | 1000 |    3    |  02-20-2015  |
|SomeActivity| 1001 |    2    |  02-30-2015  |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

The table that I need to create and keep updated would look something like this using the data from the above two tables:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Cluster  |  Eligible  |  Group  |  Activity  |  ID  |  Start Date  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Cluster1 |    True    |    1    |  Patches   | 1000 |  02-01-2015  |
|  Cluster2 |    True    |    1    |  Patches   | 1000 |  02-01-2015  |
|  Cluster3 |    True    |    2    |  Patches   | 1000 |  02-10-2015  |
|  Cluster3 |    True    |    2    |SomeActivity| 1001 |  02-30-2015  |
|  Cluster4 |    True    |    2    |  Patches   | 1000 |  02-10-2015  |
|  Cluster4 |    True    |    2    |SomeActivity| 1001 |  02-30-2015  |
|  Cluster5 |    True    |    3    |  Patches   | 1000 |  02-20-2015  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How would I create a trigger that would do this? I would just create a view but there is some user additional input that I need to accept using this merged data.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a trigger to update a 3rd table? Why not just create a view that represents the two tables joined together?

Comment: Treating the question as academic, you would need triggers on both Table 1 & 2, each comparing the inserted & deleted tables to the third table and performing the desired insert/update/delete operation on that table.

Comment: Keep the "additional input" in a third table and join those 3 tables in a view?

Comment: @diana I can't just use a view because I need the user to add additional input to the joined table.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thank you. Now I need help to create it :)

Comment: @MWillemse As an example the additional input would be a validation flag. That a user went in a checked each row and confirms it is valid data. Would love to just keep that data in a 3rd table but I would need a way to join it back to the activity which wouldn't be present.

Comment: How far have you gotten?   Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. But if you have already partially implemented stored procedures to control DMLs then why not use it for the rest too and have the stored procedure take care of it all (instead of using any triggers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. Basically what I ended up doing is created a joined view with the data from both the `cluster_metadata` and `activities_table`. From there I scripted a stored procedure which takes the appropriate data and inserts into a third table. The procedure also makes sure all the data is updated and matches the view on each execution. From there I run the procedure each time a user inputs anything to either of the tables from the web UI. Not the best solution but it's working.

Thanks everyone!